# How do I creat a box and whisker plot?

Tags: data-analysis

I know you have to create a box around the median of a data set of numbers, but I do not know where the end of the box would be placed. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your set of data, first you want to determine $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$, the lower quartile, the median, and the upper quartile, respectively. The box goes from $Q_1$ to $Q_3$, which covers the interquartile range. It is possible that some points are to the left of $Q_1$ and to the right of $Q_3$. Depending on how far they are from the plot, we call these points (extreme) outliers.

Comment: Thank you, I had to use Kahn Academy [link](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/descriptive-statistics/Box-and-whisker%20plots/v/box-and-whisker-plots) to finaly figure it out.